# I want to print the values of the 'tag (tag_ids)' in the report of 'chart of accounts.'

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am working on the accounts report where i need to print the **Tags** *(which is a many2many widget*) in the report of **Trial Balance** under the option- **Chart of Accounts**

```
Image of the section-
```

[image]

```
I was successful in adding the field of Tags in the report as shown below-
```

[image]

**Problem :-**
The problem which i'm facing is that i am not able to bring the values of tags over the report under the tags.

**Code :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <!-- Trial Balance Tag print -->
        <template id="report_trialbalance" inherit_id="account.report_trialbalance">
            <xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-condensed']//thead//tr//th" position="after">
                <th>Tags</th>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-condensed']//tbody//tr//td" position="after">
                <td t-foreach="Accounts" t-as="account">
                    <span t-att-style="style" t-esc="account['tag_ids']" t-options="{'widget': 'many2many_tags'}" />
                </td>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Please if anyone could help me out on bringing the values of tag in report,
**Thanks in advance.**